# Mouse change when dragging. Icon shape question

Tags: javascript, mouse, draggable, drag

I am trying to create drag and drop function using JavaScript.

I put the attribute 'dragable="true"' in the li tag, but it doesn't work and the mouse mark below appears.
I kept searching for this icon, but I couldn't find it.
Why is this icon displayed and What is this icon mean?
What does that earth-like shape mean?

[image]

I found that I could only drag a part of my li tag and I want to solve the problem.

```
[...images].forEach((image, index)=>{
    document.getElementById("appendedArea").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
    <li id="appended_img_${image.lastModified}" class="appended_item thumb" data-seq="${image.lastModified}" draggable="true" >
    <div class="appended_wrap img_wrap"><img src="${URL.createObjectURL(image)}" onclick="window.open(this.src)"></div>
    <button class="img_del_btn" title="${index}" data-seq="${image.lastModified}" data-index="${index}" type="button" onclick="appendedPhotoDelete(event)"></button>
    </li>`)
})
```

Comment: Some code would be useful to help.

Comment: @Geshode I uploaded my code.